# Binding Visual Studio 2015 Test Controller to Multiple IPs

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have a Visual Studio 2015 test controller with **no** agent machines configured. My test controller machine has 3 NICs. I'd like to use the "IP Switching" and "Use Multiple IPs" features, but I still only see traffic coming from a single IP.

I've configured logging `EqtTraceLevel` to `4`, and set `CreateTraceListener` to `yes`. In the `VSTTAgentProcess.log` file generated, I see no references to either "Attempting to configure IP address:" or "Configured IP address:"

How can I tell my controller to take advantage of the multiple NICs and send traffic from all available IPs?

Comment: Test controllers do not run tests. Agent computers run tests, so you would need to set up IP switching on the agents. There is some good information about IP switching in the "Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide" from http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/

Comment: Well clearly *something* is running my tests local to my controller. QTagent*.exe kicks off.

Comment: View the "agents and controllers" load test graph during or after a run. The table below it will list the computers that were used to run the test. Just configuring a controller does not use it. Visual Studio must be told to use that controller, via a `.testsettings` file.

Comment: Like I said, the controller machine is the only one involved here. I have no adjacent agent machines.

Comment: ... and the graphs show?

Comment: You'll see TLHSAWS86 which is the machine where VS2015 is running. http://imgur.com/a/qLfNf